# Material to bake, what am I doing wrong? Video included

Tags: materials, baking

Included Is a video of what I'm doing.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KRAZzMyQUYg

Comment: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this

Comment: do you mind if you can post a .blend file to look at?